# Symfony2: новичок, не совсем понимаю, где какой код должен находится

Tags: php, symfony2, pagination, doctrine2, repository

У меня есть контроллер для категорий, который должен получить список компаний данной категории, данного города, нужной страницы в нужном количестве.

```
...
$Company = $this->get('company');
$companies = $Company->getCompanies($Geo->getCityId(), $category->getCatId());
...
```

Есть сервис Company, который их получает и отшлифовывает (кому-то обрезает описание, определяет оператора для телефонов и т.д.)

Мне казалось логичным, что выборка должна лежать в репозитории и должна выдавать сервису список компаний.
Но я пользуюсь KNP пагинатором, которому нужно скормить query запрос.

И вот у меня несколько вариантов, что делать:

1. сделать репозиторий сервисом, что мне кажется почему-то неправильным, и вызывать пагинатор в нем;
2. добавить в репозиторий метод, возвращающий только query;
3. строить query прямо в сервисе.

В данным момент у меня 3-ий вариант и мне он не очень нравится:

```
$repository = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getRepository('TestBundle:Company');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('c');
$query
    ->where('c.categoryId = :catId AND c.city = :cityId')
    ->leftJoin('TestBundle:Subdomain', 'sub', 'WITH', $query->expr()->eq('c.id', 'sub.targetId'))
    ->setParameters(array(
            'catId' => $this->categoryId,
            'cityId' => $this->cityId
        ))
    ->orderBy('c.pos', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery();

$paginator  = $this->container->get('knp_paginator');
$companies = $paginator->paginate($query, $request->query->get('page', 1), 5);

if ($companies) {
    ...
}

return $companies;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо правильнее будет, чтобы репозиторий возвращал QueryBuilder, а Сервис уже делал с ним, что захочет